# urllib request for json does not match the json in browser

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

This is my code thus far.

```
url = 'https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/3014732/workouts/357031682'

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
print response 
data = json.load(response)

print data
```

The problem is that when I look at the json in the browser it is long and contains more features than I see when printing it.

To be more exact, I'm looking for the 'points' part which should be

```
data['points']['points']
```

however

```
data['points']
```

has only 2 attributes and doesn't contain the second 'points' that I do see in the url in the browser.

Could it be that I can only load 1 "layer" deep and not 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `user-agent` to your request.

Using `requests` (which `urllib` documentation recommends over directly using `urllib`), you can do:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/3014732/workouts/357031682'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla 5.0'})
print(response.json())

# long output....
```